# This code worked with the iPhone, but not with the iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

```
urlAddress = @"file://@tableofcontents.html";

url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"tableofcontents" withExtension:@"html"];

html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

[instructions.InstructionsBrowser loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[url URLByDeletingLastPathComponent]];
```

Comment: Could you help us out by telling us what happens when you run on the iPad?

Comment: Also, what is `requestObj`? You're not using it apart from assigning to it. We need more context and some text to explain what's actually happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to replace the last line with:

```
[instructions.InstructionsBrowser loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tableofcontents" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```